# What's the difference between 16.04 and 16.04.1?

Tags: 16.04

So I downloaded and installed Ubuntu Desktop yesterday on a laptop and I noticed that there is a newer 16.04.1 version. I got the 16.04... I think. Would it say ".1" otherwise in system details?

What's the difference?

Answer (score 5):

16.04.1 just has some updates and bug fixes. It's not a new release or anything, and simply running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` on a 16.04.0 computer would bring it to 16.04.1.

I believe they make these point releases so that users are able to install Ubuntu with more up-to-date packages OOTB. Otherwise, anyone installing 16.04 would be installing packages and security updates from early April.

I think of the point releases as something like Service Packs on Windows (Service Packs from the days of Windows XP and 2000, when they actually mattered). They're not a whole new OS, but they come with bug fixes and security patches, and are installable through normal updates.

Comment: Also I think it may prevents some bugs during Ubnutu installation using a live media on some systems.

Comment: @Dante as in "bug fixes"? :P

Comment: On Ubuntu I have always used `dist-upgrade` rather than just `upgrade`.

Comment: @kasperd I didn't realize `dist-upgrade` covered what `upgrade` does.

Comment: @Zacharee1 I think it's impossible to update an unbootable/disconnected `16.04` ;-)

Comment: So if I installed 16.04 and the software updater tool says that my system is up to date, then I already have the same patches that are otherwise included with 16.04.1? But my version number will always stay at "16.04"? It will not flip to "16.04.1"? With Windows XP you could tell if SP2 was installed. Doesn't work like that on Ubuntu?

Comment: What are these patches that called for a "dot" and a one? They must be very important? No? I can't connect to WiFi on this install, so I'm thinking that it might be related somehow?

Comment: @sammyg they're not necessarily super important. It's just that Canonical occasionally repackages LTS releases with updates. They could include security patches and they might not. If WiFi isn't working, that's a different issue.

Comment: On a second thought... this might explain why software updater told me that the system is up to date... it never actually checked because WiFi is not on.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to Windows Service Packs if it is more familiar.

Ubuntu 16.04.1 is an installation image that includes package updates.

If you installed regular updates, your version has been updated to 16.04.1.

Comment: Or perhaps is more current than the latest point release. ;-)

Comment: @ElderGeek I don't think 16.04.0 is considered a point release at all; they start at 16.04.1.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος That's true. My point is relevant to future point releases beyond .1 My apologies for any confusion this may have caused you.

Answer (score 1):

Point releases have bug fixes and updates rolled in. If you've installed 16.04 and are current on your updates the only difference (AFAIK) is you might have a more up to date system than the current point release.